# Can't change the boot order on UEFI BIOS

Tags: boot, usb, bios

I've searched for an answer already, but I may not be using the right terminology. Regardless, I wasn't able to find an answer.

I bought a mini PC with an eMMC HD and I'm trying to overwrite the existing OS (Windows 10) with a distribution of Linux from a USB drive. I changed the boot order to run all possible USB devices (there were five listed) before the HD, but it kept loading Windows. Eventually, I removed the HD from the boot order altogether and it's still booting to Windows. I'm not sure how this is possible, but it seems to be overriding my boot order preferences.

I read in a few places to disable Secure Boot. That's disabled. I also read that it should be installed in CSM mode, but that's not an option that I can see.

I don't know if this is worth mentioning, but it's the Aptio Setup Utility by American Megatrends.

Help?

Answer (score 1):

1. Try using a different USB drive preferably a different brand
2. Try plugging in the USB drive in the first port (If you don't know which one is first just try all the ports).
3. In the bios usb settings there will be option to toggle between legacy mode or uefi mode (legacy for booting from a USB drive configured to boot as legacy or uefi to boot as uefi , on some systems it matters).
4. Sometimes the usb needs to be specifically configured to boot on a uefi bios  Are you sure you have burned a bootable image of the linux on the USB drive - RUFUS is a great tool to make sure the USB drive is setup as bootable(But please go through the said linux help pages thoroughly to configure your USB drive.
5. System dependent - one of the function keys can be used to bring up
   a boot page , from which you can choose to boot from a specific
   drive(usually F2 F8 F10 F12).